# Promise then return undefined in thunk dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to redirect user to somewhere if he/she is logged in, I can use Promise to do this but my redux thunk async doesn't return anything in the response back to the component.

```
export function loginUser(email,password){
  return dispatch=>{

    return axios.post('auth/login', {email,password})
      .then(res=>{
        if(res.status===200 && res.data.status===1){

          //things are working here
          dispatch({
            type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data.data
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(res => { 
        dispatch(errorMsg(res.data.msg))
      })
  }
}
```

In my component I did

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.loginUser('username', 'pass')
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp) //this is undefined?!
  })
}
```

I tried this

```
return dispatch({
  type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
  payload: res.data.data
})
```

It doesn't work too.

Except using then, what else can I do to redirect user to logged in page?

Answer (score 2):

You have to return from the Promise's `.then()` and `.catch()` callbacks as well:

```
export function loginUser(email,password){
  return dispatch=>{

    return axios.post('auth/login', {email,password})
      .then(res=>{
        if(res.status===200 && res.data.status===1){

          //things are working here
          dispatch({
            type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data.data
          })

          // return when success
          return {
            type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data.data
          }
        }

        // return if failed, you can also return Promise.reject to invoke the .catch
        return "something" 
      })
      .catch(res => { 
        dispatch(errorMsg(res.data.msg))

        // return error message
        return res.data.msg;
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: if I do not want to use then(), in redux how can I check the user is logged in in the component? return multiple same object doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Use react-redux connect to get the user's status from redux's state.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Promise like

```
export function loginUser(email,password){
  return dispatch=>{
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post('auth/login', {email,password})
      .then(res=>{
        if(res.status===200 && res.data.status===1){
          resolve(res.data.data)
          //things are working here
          dispatch({
            type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data.data
          })
        }
        reject(res.status)
      })
      .catch(res => { 
        reject(res);
        dispatch(errorMsg(res.data.msg))
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: look redundant because return axios is already a Promise. What if I want to use redux to check whether user is logged it, how it would look like? I don't want to use componentWillRecieiveProps coz it's going to be deprecated.